# Clickling on a open nautilus window's icon opens new window

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive

When I connect an external HardDrive to my computer and open it using Nautilus (for browsing files), clicking on the nautilus icon (which has an open window indicator) just open a new Nautilus window, instead of focusing on the HardDrive window.

Scrolling on the icon using the mouse-wheel does focus the right window.

It doesn't happen when the open window is of folder on the current computer.

What can I do to fix this?

Alternatively, how, when I open my harddrive for file browsing, can I show the window under the harddrive icon in the launcher rather under the Nautilus icon?

Comment: This a known bug: [#1170647](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647)

Comment: Seems to me more like an unwanted feature. Hoped there's a way to turn it off via dconf-editor.

Comment: No, it is a bug. You cannot "turn it off", unless it is fixed.